# I don't understand UTC date formatting using DateFormat in Dart

Tags: dart, date-format

When UTC date is formatted by `DateFormat#format()`, I expect to get a `String` of UTC date formatted, but not.

Please look at the code below. These tests are passed.

My question is why does `DateFormat#format()` return a time of 12:00 past UTC date? What am I missing here?

```dart
Date date(int millisecondsSinceEpoch, bool isUtc) =>
    new Date.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch(millisecondsSinceEpoch, isUtc:isUtc);

DateFormat df = new DateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm");

// JST (+9.00)
expect(date(0, false).toString(), equals("1970-01-01 09:00:00.000"));
expect(df.format(date(0, false)), equals("1970-01-01 09:00"));

expect(date(0, true).toString(), equals("1970-01-01 00:00:00.000Z"));
// Why 12 o'clock?
expect(df.format(date(0, true)), equals("1970-01-01 12:00"));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your format string you've written uses lowercase `hh` which is a 12 hour clock.  Use uppercase `HH` for the hours to get a 24-hour clock.  The output you are getting in the last line is currently saying 12 midnight, rather than 00 hours in a 24-hour clock.

See the explicit pattern syntax in [DateFormat](http://api.dartlang.org/docs/bleeding_edge/intl/DateFormat.html)

Comment: @TomochikaHara be sure to accept the answer if it's correct. :) There's a checkmark underneath the "vote up or down" for the answer.

Comment: I see. Thank you for your indication, @Seth !